# Next value of primary key

Tags: c#, database, increment

How can I find NEXT value of auto increment databse table or the current, without open new connection, on primary key in c#?

Is there a method in C#?

Comment: I imagine to get the "current" value you'd select the top 1 record from that table ordering by that field descending.  And to get the "next" value you'd insert a record into that table and examine the generated value in that record.  What are you actually trying to accomplish and why?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way to **reliably** fetch the NEXT key, is to insert a row and obtain it. I would advise against attempting to predict the next key, as there will always be the possibility it has changed by the time you perform your insert.

Comment: There is no reliable way to determine the next value of an auto-increment (IDENTITY) column in SQL Server. The value is not guaranteed until after the INSERT has actually happened.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 4):

There is no reliable way to do this, because it would automatically be a race condition. In fact, more than that: it could lead to phantom values. Specifically: if you do an insert requiring a new `IDENTITY` value, and then *roll back the transaction*, the table's identity  *does not revert*: there will be a gap. This again: is deliberate.

There is, in SQL Server, an `IDENT_CURRENT(object)` function that returns the *previous* identity value for the table - but there are very few scenarios (other than informational tools) where you should use it. You certainly shouldn't use it to prime secondary inserts.

The usual approach here is:

- do the insert
- let the database tell you what the new `IDENTITY` value is (`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in SQL Server)
- use that value

alternatively, you can do some interesteng multi-part inserts using an [`OUTPUT` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your DBMS.

For SQL Server 2008 or newer you can get useful information from `sys.index`, `sys.index_columns` and `sys.identity_columns`:

```
select object_name(i.object_id) tableName
    , i.name indexName
    , c.name columnName
    , c.is_identity
    , idc.seed_value
    , idc.increment_value
    , idc.last_value
from    sys.indexes i
        inner join 
        sys.index_columns ic on  ic.object_id = i.object_id 
                             and ic.index_id = i.index_id
        inner join 
        sys.columns c on  c.object_id = ic.object_id 
                      and c.column_id = ic.column_id
        left outer join 
        sys.identity_columns idc on  idc.object_id = c.object_id 
                                 and idc.column_id = c.column_id
where i.is_primary_key = 1
```

As others mentioned in comments the `last_value` can change between the moment you fetched it and the moment you use it. However, there are methods to avoid this problem although I don't recommend using it:

- begin a transaction
- get the next expected value for identity column
- do work normally making use of the value obtained above
- check that indeed the used value was the expected one
- if everything is OK commit transaction
- otherwise rollback transaction and try again.